# What is the direction of area vector while calculating flux in AC generators?

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, electromagnetic-induction

I was told that in case of an open surface, the direction of area vector is considered to be in the direction of magnetic field but my doubt is won't the direction of area vector change as armature rotates in magnetic field?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118697/what-is-the-direction-of-area-vector-while-calculating-magnetic-flux